# Counterexample for disproving continuity of $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^\omega$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Define $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^\omega$ such that $f(t) = (t, 2t, 3t, \dots)$, where $\mathbb R$ is given the standard topology, and $\mathbb R^\omega$ is given the uniform topology. I'm trying to prove f is not continuous. Here is my attempt at a counterexample;

Let $U = B(0,1) = \{x \in \mathbb R^\omega: ||x|| < 1\}$. Now $U$ is open as an open unit ball, and $f^{-1}(U)$ is such that if $x \in f^{-1}(U)$ then $nx < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z_+$. In particular this implies $x < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$ so $x = 0$ and $f^{-1}(U) = \{0\}$ is closed.  Is this a correct counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed mean $f$ is not continuous?  (Yes, I know how it would go, but it is a rather long-winded way to do so.)

It is better to say $f^{-1}(U)=\{0\}$ is not open, then it is just the definition of continuity to reach the desired conclusion.

Comment: It seems like I need to take a break. Indeed, I meant to write that $\{0\}$ is not open. However, the example seems to work? I didn't bother to mention the definition of continuity since in my mind I wrote: "... is not open... " which implies discontinuity.

Comment: yes, the example works.